# Is a stem word required with a prefix and suffix combination?

Tags: suffixes, prefixes

Suppose the following lexeme:

> mononess

Consisting of the prefix "mono-" (meaning "one") and suffix "-ness" (meaning "the quality of"), but no stem/root word.

Could this lexeme be a valid word in the English language?

If so, is this construction allowed explicitly or implicitly ("not disallowed" by any rule)? Also, are there examples of any real words that follow this pattern?

Comment: In general, a prefix or a suffix needs a root. Neither can attach itself to another of its class: (prefix-suffix) is not a word. Semantic analysis will go bonkers.

Comment: @Kris That's OK; it's often where semantic analysis starts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no.

Yes because it's possible, but no because technically when you want to do this, you are lexicalizing one of them and then adding on the [pre|suf]ix to that base word and so are no longer strictly using a prefix and a suffix together.

So in the case of *mononess*, you aren't referring to a singularity of quality, rather the quality of being one/singular, so *mono-* is lexicalized as *mono*<sup>1</sup> to which the suffix *-ness* is added.  I could perhaps understand someone talking about the *preness* of something (the quality of coming before, or *pre-* + *-ness*), but I think I'd definitely need a hyphen to actually mentally decompose the word properly.

In the case of *mononess* though, it's a bit hypothetical, since the word *oneness* is already regularly used for the concept.  In fact, I reckon most any combination will likely be better served by some other word or phrasing.

---

<sup>1. I'm ignoring the fact that apparently *mono* is already an adjective mainly because its glosses are *monochrome* and *monophonic* which don't apply here (that and I've neither seen nor used it)</sup>

Comment: +1 A real-world example: in the 1980s the St Louis Cardinals had a player, Jose Oquendo, who was an accomplished backup for every position on the field - he even pitched a couple of times. He was often referred to in the media as the Cards' ***supersub***.

Comment: The *sub* in 'supersub' is **a word, a noun,** not a prefix at all. What's the problem with 'supersub' then? (Short for *substitute,* as you already are aware.) Even a great sub-editor will be proud to earn the epithet of a 'supersub,' why not?